# ListView is black on some Devices

Tags: android, xml, listview

On my Main Activity is a ListView but on some Devices like Galaxy s3 the item are black but on my S4 it is shown normal and i can see the text. i tried android:background="@android:color/transparent but it is still black, also android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" dosen´t help. I hope someone can help.

MainActivity:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>
```

ListView only first title without content textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/list_item_border"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >


<!--     <style android:name="Divider">
    <item android:name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item android:name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that you are describing. It looks like you also have a custom view for displaying the listview items - so this might work for you aswell!

I have overridden the getView method in my "CustomAdapter", a class that extends ArrayAdapter. And in the getView method in that class I set all the items that is non-selected to a drawable - and it is important that the drawable has a solid color - like this:

(This is the R.drawable.item_default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

My issue was solved by doing this. Below is the code to my extended class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int viewResourceId;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;
    private int selectedTextView;
    private Context myContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,int resourceId, int textViewId, 
        ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        super(activity,resourceId,textViewId, list);

        // Sets the layout inflater
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Set a copy of the layout to inflate
        viewResourceId = resourceId;

        selectedTextView = textViewId;

        myContext = context;

        // Set a copy of the list
        items = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;

        if (layout == null) {
            layout = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(selectedTextView);

        tv.setText(items.get(position));

        // Change the background color
        if (position==selectedPosition){
            tv.setBackground(myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_pressed));
        }
        else {
            tv.setBackground(myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_default));
        }

        return layout;
    }

    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }
}
```

The black listview was only showing when I ran the app on a Galaxy S2. It was transparent like I wanted on my S4 Mini - hopefully this might help you in some extent!